# In Word 2007, how can I change the paragraph format for *only* the first list level?

Tags: microsoft-word-2007, text-formatting

I have a multi-level bulleted list in word. I want items on the highest level to be visually separated by adding additional line spacing after each of them. I do not want there to be any spacing between items on the second level.

The following formatting shows what I want:

```
    - Item level 1 
         * Item level 2
         * Another Item level 2 

    - Another Item level 1
```

However, I could only increase spacing between all items, meaning that there was an empty line between items Level 2 too.

Any ideas on how I can accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [We have multi-level list where we try to change the line spacing](http://microsoft.public.word.numbering.narkive.com/LJsL53NP/we-have-multi-level-list-where-we-try-to-change-the-line-spacing) :

> The list formatting does not include
>   line spacing. To have different line
>   spacing for each level in the list,
>   associate a unique paragraph style
>   (with the desired line spacing
>   defined) with each numbering level.
>
> Here's how to do that: Place the
>   insertion point in the first top-level
>   item of your list. On the Home tab,
>   click Multilevel List and then click
>   Define New Multilevel List. In the
>   dialog box, first click the More
>   button to see all options (if
>   necessary). Then, for each level,
>   choose a style name in the "Link level
>   to style" box. When you are done,
>   click OK.
>
> Note that assigning a paragraph style
>   for each numbering level has been the
>   recommended approach for Word versions
>   97 and later. The difference is that
>   Word 2007 no longer allows you to
>   access the numbering options via the
>   top-level paragraph style (which was
>   the recommended approach in older
>   versions.
>
> The new approach offered by Word 2007
>   is to create a list style, via Home
>   tab | Multilevel List | Define New
>   List Style. Once created, a list style
>   appears at Home tab | Multilevel List
>   (under "List Styles"). The advantage
>   of list styles is that they can be
>   modified via the Modify Style dialog
>   box like any other style, but note
>   that list styles do not replace
>   assigning paragraph styles to
>   numbering levels.

Comment: The original article is no longer available, and I'm not entirely sure I understand the instructions provided.

Comment: @StevenVascellaro: I found an alternate link, but the answer contains all the text. Just follow the above instructions, remembering that this is for Word 2007.

Comment: I am still having trouble following the steps in its current format.